# Load MySQL Data to PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is the front end of my code. I need auto load the database contents when i select the CUID. Example if i select Customer ID 1, then it should auto load the data to the relevant fields.
Can anyone help me on what needs to be done?

[image]

Below is the current code;

Customer Profile Search Page

```
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Customer Profile Search Page</h1>
    <blockquote>
        <div>
            <form>
                <label>Customer ID</label>
                <select name="cus_id" id="cus_id" class="combo">

                    <?php
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "cusAdmin";
                    $password = "123456";
                    $dbname = "cusid";

                    //create connection
                    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                    if ($conn->connection_error) {
                        die("connection failed: " . $conn->connection_error);
                    }
                    $sql = "select * from custprofile";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            //echo "id: " . $row["cus_id"]. "name:" . $row[cus_name]. "dof:" . $row[dob]. "doj:" . $row[cuEmail]."<br>"; 
                            echo "<option value='" . $row["cus_id"] . "'>" . $row["cus_id"] . "</option>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }
                    $conn->close();

                    ?>          
                </select>
                <br>
                <label>Customer Name</label><input type="text" name="cusname"><br>
                <label>Date of Birth</label><input type="text" name="dob"><br>
                <label>Date of Join</label><input type="text" name="doj"><br>
                <label>Phone No</label><input type="text" name="phone"><br>
                <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email"><br>
                <label>Gender</label><select name="gender">
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                    <option value="other">other</option>
                </select><br>
                <label>Address</label><textarea name="message" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea><br>


                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </blockquote>

</body>
```

`

Comment: you will need to use ajax and an `onchange` event handler by the look of it

Comment: Auto fill only for cus_id field?

Comment: There must be **10,000** simple tutorials available on the net, use google to find one. **SO is not a free coding or tutorial service** Or possibly you could try the [PHP Manual - Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) _Its a radical idea I know_

Comment: @devpro Cus_id is auto filling from the database. Now i want to auto fill the rest of the fields that corresponds to the cusid1, cusid2 when the relevant cusid is selected

Comment: Than it means this is your edit form.. And I think u have also an I'd in URL to???

Comment: And don't forget to read what @riggsfolly suggest

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo code to help you get started.

```
<?php
    /* 
        place at top of the same script as the form as the ajax uses the current location.href as url
        alternatively use a separate script and change the url in the ajax function
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['cus_id'] ) ){
        ob_clean();

        /* prepare variables */
        $cust_id=$_POST['cus_id'];
        /* etc */

        /* prepare sql */
        $sql='select * from table where cust_id=$cust_id';
        /* execute sql */

        /* return recordset to ajax callback */
        print_r( $recordset );
        exit();
    }
?>

<script>
    ( function(){

        var bindEvents=function(){/* assign onchange event handler */
            document.getElementById('cus_id').onchange=evtHandler;
        };

        var evtHandler=function(event){/* the event handler fires off an ajax request ( via POST )*/
            var el=event.target || event.srcElement;
            ajax.call( this, 'post', document.location.href, { cust_id:el.options[ el.options.selectedIndex ].value }, evtCallback );
        };

        var evtCallback=function( response ){/* callback function to populate form fields */
            alert('use the response data ['+response+'] to populate the form fields');
        };

        var ajax=function(m,u,p,c){/* basic ajax function */
            /* 
                m=method, u=url, p=params(object), c=callback
            */
            var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call(this,xhr.response);
            };
            var params=[];
            for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

            switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                case 'post': p=params; break;
                case 'get': u+='?'+params; p=null; break;   
            }

            xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send( p );
        };

        document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, false );
    }());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a separation between your controller and your markup.

Before the `</body>` close tag, load jquery and create the following script :

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script> <!--- Load jquery here --->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cus_id').change(function() {
            var cusId = $(this).val();
            getData(cusId);
        });

        function getData(cusId) {
            $.get('ajax.php?cus_id=' + cusId)
                .success(function(data) {
                    $('input[name="cusname"]').val(data.cusname);
                    // ... Fill all your fields with the retrieved data.
                })
                .error(function(error) {
                    alert(error);
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

In the php script, just make an SQL query like done in your template :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "cusAdmin";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "cusid";

//create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connection_error) {
    die("connection failed: " . $conn->connection_error);
}

$sql='select * from custprofile where cus_id = $_GET["cus_id"]';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

// Return the result
return json_encode($data);
```

[See PDO prepared statements for more security.](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Hopes this help you.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to provide such a user experience is via [AJAX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

You can handcode your implementation or use a third party library, like [ANGULARJS](https://angularjs.org).

Keep in mind that you are server side querying user's data, then you need to passs it to the DOM on the backs without the user noticing it.
By using just PHP, you are forcing the user to experience two trips, first when the form is deployed and second when the server responds to selected user id request in the form.

AJAX will conceal and even make that faster, by working in the backstage, fetching data from the server without noticing.

There are thousands, yes thousands of tutorials of how to do it.